# Populate the cell which are visible on screen in table layout

Tags: android

Let's say i have a 100 rows*100 columns table layout containing button for each cell. It means 10000 buttons. As the data for each cell is taken through a web request which is not possible for 10000 cells. So i want to populate the data for only those cell which are visible on screen. Is it possible to have data visible only for those cell which are currently visible on screen.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GridView`. Also if you will get the images from the web you should get them asynchronously and I would reccomend using [`DroidFu WebImageView`](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/). Here is the [`DroidFu Google project`](https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu).

Comment: Thanks Ovidiu..but is it not possible to know the number of cells for which the requested need to be hit?

Comment: I cannot use grid view as it does not support horizontal scrolling..and i need horizontal as well as vertical scrolling.

Comment: Then you could place the GridView inside a HorizontalScrollView but this will lead to odd behaviours.